# Converting a Time to 24 hour time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2000 and need to convert my time column to 24 hour time instead of just 9:30 AM, 12:30 PM, etc.  I'm trying to sort this column and I believe its not working because its just looking at things numerically instead of as the time.  I think what I need can be done with the function FORMAT(Time, HH:mm:ss), but that doesn't  seem to be a function in SQL Server, so I'm stuck now.

Comment: The sorting should be correct if the column is of type DateTime. The string you're seeing is just a representation of the underlying time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`CONVERT(char(5), GETDATE(), 108)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Is that going to convert an existing column's value or just get the current time?

Comment: @gdawgrancid: change GETDATE to your value. If the value isn't datetime then CAST first to datetime.

Answer (score 1):

First time I post something! I had to convert from M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss AM/PM to Datetime. Please note my localtime is DD-MM-YYYY so I had to convert in that format before converting to Datetime. Field name to convert was "Valeur" in table N_IsaacForm. Here is how I did it in SQL 2008:

```
select NIF.Valeur, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PM',NIF.Valeur) = 0 
THEN CONVERT(datetime,substring(NIF.Valeur, P2.Pos + 1, P3.Pos - P2.Pos - 1) + '-'
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, P3.Pos + 1, P4.Pos - P3.Pos - 3),8) + '-'
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, P1.Pos + 1, P2.Pos - P1.Pos - 1),2) + ' ' 
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, 1, P1.Pos-1),2))
--add 12 hours if PM
ELSE DATEADD(hour,12,CONVERT(datetime,substring(NIF.Valeur, P2.Pos + 1, P3.Pos - P2.Pos - 1) + '-'
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, P3.Pos + 1, P4.Pos - P3.Pos - 3),8) + '-'
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, P1.Pos + 1, P2.Pos - P1.Pos - 1),2) + ' ' 
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, 1, P1.Pos-1),2)))
END

FROM N_IsaacForm AS NIF (nolock)    
cross apply (select (charindex('/', NIF.Valeur))) as P1(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex('/', NIF.Valeur, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex(' ', NIF.Valeur, P2.Pos+1))) as P3(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex('M', NIF.Valeur, P3.Pos+1))) as P4(Pos)
WHERE CHARINDEX('M',NIF.Valeur) > 0 --(I had other values in the table with   proper format)
```

You just have to change the order of the elements to set your particular local time.

Results obtained

1. 8/20/2015 1:11:31 AM  --->  2015-08-20 01:11:31.000
2. 8/19/2015 10:37:32 PM --->   2015-08-19 22:37:32.000
3. 10/7/2015 8:51:37 PM  --->  2015-10-07 20:51:37.000
4. 9/8/2015 3:27:17 PM   ---> 2015-09-08 15:27:17.000

Hope it may help someone ! I've found so much help on this site !

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with this one,

```
select CONVERT(time, CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(date, getdate()))+ ' 02:24 PM', 120)
```

the above query will return 14:24:00.0000000

If you want only the time part ignoring the milli seconds,

```
select convert(varchar(8),CONVERT(time, CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(date, getdate()))+ ' 02:24 PM', 120))
```

I tested the above in SQL 2008 and it works fine.