# Convert DateTime to 24 Hrs Format using Sql Server 2012 - I know it's Duplicate

Tags: sql-server

I have used the following [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892051/converting-a-time-to-24-hour-time-in-sql-server) to accomplish this but with no luck

```
CONVERT(CHAR(5),CAST(Logtime AS DATETIME),108)
```

and then tried this

```
 CONVERT(CHAR(5),CAST(Logtime AS DATETIME),114)
```

None of the above is working it is giving me the same output for example;
In passed this - `2015-05-27 01:00:00.000` and get back this - `01:00`
But I am expecting this - `13:00`

Comment: 2015-05-27 01:00:00.000 has two meanings may it is 1 am or it may be 1 pm . how can sql server find you want 1 pm so you have to mention that ???so if you just only give 2015-05-27 01:00:00.000 then you will not get 24 hour format  use something like 2015-05-27 01:00:00.000 PM

Answer (score 2):

```
CONVERT(CHAR(5),CAST(Logtime AS DATETIME),108)
```

This is right way.

but Your data is wrong.
In passed this - **2015-05-27 01:00:00.000 PM**

Then you get expecting result